# How to stretch width to 100% of scrollable area?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to stretch the red div to 100% of the scrollable area, i.e. to the have blue's width but without hard coding red's width.

```css
.outer {
  overflow: auto;
}

.blue {
  width: 200em;
  background: blue;
}

.red {
  width: 100%;/*does not work */
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="blue">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="red">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxqEMy

Comment: you can add anothe wrapper?

Comment: you mean one with `display: inline-block;`? not sure have to check carefully... would be great without

Comment: yes, you make the outer inline-block and then another wrapper where you apply the overflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can change the HTML,  add another wrapper like this:

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
}

.outer {
  display: inline-block;
}

.blue {
  width: 200em;
  background: blue;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="blue">
      Test
    </div>
    <div class="red">
      Test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can move the width declaration of the blue element to the parent element using CSS variable so that you can use it in the red one:

```css
.outer {
  overflow: auto;
  --w:200em;
}

.blue {
  width:var(--w);
  background: blue;
}

.red {
  width: var(--w);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="blue">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="red">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But why? I would appreciate a logical explanation of what's going on. I feel like sometimes CSSer's just mess around with things until they pop into place, but I would like to properly understand what's going on. (any recommendation on high-level / advanced CSS info would be great too!)

Comment: @CodeAt30 why what? :) there is no advanced CSS here, I simply moved the overflow to another wrapper to allow the width:100% to work ... I don't see what explanation I can add to this. Should I explain what is an inline-block element? or how width:100% works? ... also for the second case, it's trivial, I declared a variable and I use it, what is not clear?

Comment: Thanks. The second version does not work because I don't know the width beforehand. The first did. In my specific case, I just had to add `min-width: 100%` to `.outer` for it to stretch when the container was wider than it's content.

Comment: @Daniel I also forget to remove the width:100%, it's useless in this case ;) .. code updated

Comment: @TemaniAfif It's not a criticism about your answer. It's great i upvoted it as well. But for instance, I do not understand why wouldn't width of an element - when using a dynamic unit such as `em, %, vw` etc, is ignoring overflow.

I can assume there are structural reasons for the way CSS handles overflow etc. But its like i always end up getting the how-to quick fix rather than the in-depth CSS-and-how-it-works under-the-hood explanation.

Whenever i look up advanced CSS or something like that i end up with info about how to use css-transitions etc. which honestly is simply not advanced

Comment: In shorter terms, I could've fidgeted around with the html and reach the answers you gave but rebuilding the structure a little bit. I've also done a lot of CSS and am fairly competent at building very interactive and complex things with it. Yet i still feel like i don't actually understand what is going on under the hood and it's frustrating me. (Also this has stopped being at all relevant to the question or answer sorry about that) @TemaniAfif

Comment: @CodeAt30 well in this particular case simply add border to outer element, remove/add the overlow and you will see what is happening .. basically  the elemetn is a block element so it's width is 100% by default and actually it's the width of the screen (you can see this in the dev tool) AND the blue is overflowing because it's width is bigger ... for the red element we defined 100% which mean 100% of outer and outer 100% is the screen so it won't go beyond, we also don't even need 100% because red is also a block element and it's by default. so it's not ignoring overflow but respecting width

Comment: @CodeAt30 you are probably thinking that the width of the element is bigger becasue there is a scroll, but not, the width of the element is what you see not the width of what is inside (you can easily check this with dev tools)

Answer (score 1):

Just give their *parent element* `display: grid`, which will then expand the `.red` one to its `width`, which is dictated by the `width` of the `.blue` one. This works fine as long as the `overflow: auto` is *"being used"*.

```css
.outer {
  display: grid;
  overflow: auto;
}

.blue {
  width: 200em;
  background: blue;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="blue">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="red">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, you can also do it with the *Flexbox* (works in Firefox):

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.blue {
  width: 200em;
  background: blue;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="blue">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="red">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

And for Chrome with the help of additional wrapper (also works in Firefox):

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}

.outer {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.blue {
  width: 200em;
  background: blue;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="blue">
      Test
    </div>
    <div class="red">
      Test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```